# How to detect when mathjax is fully loaded?

Tags: mathjax

Is there anyway to identify when the mathjax is fully loaded to process mathematics. I need to hide my mathematics equations before mathjax is fully loaded and show 'loading' message in mean time.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For those who might be looking for the answer, this is the response i got from Mathjax developer

> The way to synchronize with MathJax's startup actions it to register a StartupHook that will fire when the startup is complete. For example, you can use
>
> `MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("End",function () { ... your startup code here ... });`
>
> at the end of the  tag that configures MathJax, or in a
> separate  tag just after loading MathJax if you are using the
> default MathJax configuration file in MathJax/config/MathJax.js. That
> should let you hook into MathJax's initialization sequence so you can
> do your own setup at the right time.

Thanks David

Comment: You have to add the code above in the `<script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> ... </script>` block, not in the javascript block.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Jquery loaded you can use [getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

```
var mjaxURL  = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML,Safe.js';
// load mathjax script
$.getScript(mjaxURL, function() {
    // mathjax successfully loaded, let it render
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, 'c'+parentid+'_list']);
});
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Added the recommended CDN: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure when the `pageReady` callback is called, but my current solution is:

```js
window.mathjax_loaded = false
MathJax = {
  startup: {
    pageReady: () => {
      console.log('Running MathJax');                                                                                                                             
      window.mathjax_loaded = true // PUT YOUR CODE HERE
      return MathJax.startup.defaultPageReady();
    }
  }
};
const func = () => {
  if( window.mathjax_loaded ) {                                                                                                                                           
    // do something only if mathjax is loaded
  }
}
```