# How to get value from r.fn.init (JQuery selector context)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I try to receive a value from span from table like this:

```
function getValueFromSibling(this) {
    var id = $(this).parent().siblings('span.childSibbling');
}
```

Table looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" onClick="getValueFromSibling()"></button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="childSibbling">100</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But I receive something like this:

`id = r.fn.init [prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]`

I found that is simple form of:

```
var jQuery = function( selector, context ){
   return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
};
```

So there is the question. How to receive `InnerHTML` from `<span>`, or how to convert `r.fn.init [prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]` to value?

`var result = id.val();` and var result = `id.get();` dosen't work

Comment: try `$('span.sibbling').html()`?

Comment: unfortunately it gives undefined

Comment: You don't want a sibling, you want a child of a sibling.

Comment: yes bad naming.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, `this` inside your function `getValueFromSibling` is in window scope pass `this` context when calling the function

```
 onClick="getValueFromSibling(this)"
```

And there are few things missing like `text()` to get the text you want. Try one below

Better way (actually recommended way):

Html

```
<tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="some-button"></button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="sibbling">100</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
  $('.some-button').click(function(){
      var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.sibbling').text();
          // .closest() gets the closest tr parent .
          // .find() finds the element with class 'sibbling' inside that `tr`
          // .text() gets the text inside the element.
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok it works! But I don't have answer how to get value from r.fn.init.

Comment: I like this but it has a problem. `closest` and `find` would give you ANY '.sibling' and not necesary the next or adjacent one.

Comment: @frikinside problem?  Can you point it out I might have missed something here.. :)

Comment: @frikinside well, closest() will  get the first element that matches the selector so in this case will be the first parent `tr` (even if there is another tr above it, it will find the first parent tr) which will always be the same and `find()` will search for `sibling` inside it. Hope that solved your concern.

Comment: Sure, but with another "match" inside the `tr` for that selector maybe you get something unwanted. For example, with another preceding `td` with same class. I don't know if in the real case of the OP this would be possible, but maybe is interesting to point that out, just as disclaimer. I don't know if I made my point correctly, my english is awful :/

Comment: Yup I agree. There will be other cases too say OP adds another <tr> above the button and span is not included in that `tr`. So ya DOM manipulation entirely depends on how the HTML structure is :) :)... Anyways Thanks

Comment: @frikinside And ya good point. Also, your english I guess is better than mine.  :) .. Happy Coding.

Comment: Like I said to @Adriano in another comment, two differents aproachs with differents repercusions. Happy Coding to you too!

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to get the text value by using

```
$("selector").text();
```

Comment: You can't even imagine how helpful this was for me

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that you don't want a sibling, you want a child of a sibling.

```js
function getValueFromSibling(me) {
    var id = $(me).parent().next().find('span.childSibbling').text();
    console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" onClick="getValueFromSibling(this)"></button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="childSibbling">100</span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

With this, first we do a `.parent()` to move us on the `td` element. Then, we move on the next `td` element with `.next()` and finally, recover the `span.childSibbling` with `find('span.childSibbling')`.
Using the method `.text()` for recover the `innerText` of the node or `.html()` for the innerHTML of the node.

For the `r.fn.init` question, there is an excelent answer in [this questio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494873/why-is-my-jquery-selector-returning-a-n-fn-init0-and-what-is-it)n.

Comment: Ok I think I understand how it works, but if there is more `td` elements in this row element before `span` with class `sibbling` it isn't best solution.

Comment: @Adriano Sorry, there was a typo, I made it toa a script and now is returning the value correctly. About your comment, You are right, this is the solution only for the next (and only next) td. bipen answer don't focus on that and pick ANY of the elements with that class. Different aproachs with different repercusions. Choose wisely ;)