# How to console log input val?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to apply to an `input.val()` a `text` from a `span` element but when I try to check it in `console` I don't get it.

```js
$("#sandbox-container span").on("click", function(e) {
      $("#sandbox-container span").removeClass("selected_year");
      $(this).attr("class", "selected_year");
      var dateSelected = $(".selected_year").text();
      var dateCat = $(".time_value").val(dateSelected);
      console.log(dateSelected);
      console.log(dateCat);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sandbox-container">
      <span class="selected_year">2014</span>
      <span>2018</span>
    </div>
<input label="null" style="display: none;" class="time_value" maxlength="99" name="usp-category" type="text" value="">
```

The above gives me:

```
2014
(index):208 r.fn.init [prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
```

While I would expect `console.log(dateCat);` to give me `2014`

Comment: That code seems to work? Or at least doesn't error. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) of your problem

Comment: were is `.usp-input-category`, I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @Keith yes just updated, was missing the input. Yet now they have changed my code and I am more confused as it is giving both text values and the issue changed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you pass a value to the function, you're setting the value of the element not obtaining it, the jQuery methods follow a chaining pattern, so they actually return the element itself so if you want to set a value and then retrieve it:

```
var dateCat = $(".usp-input-category").val(dateSelected);

console.log(dateCat.val())
```

Just so you're aware, class selectors i.e. `$(".usp-input-category")` return an array. So running `.val` with a value in the constructor on the array will change the value for all the elements with this class.

The `.val` function, when constructor is empty, will return the value of the element, where as when a constructor is called with a value, it'll return the element itself.

Worth noting differences between `.val()`, `.text()` as the later is probably the function you should look at.

- `.val` gets/sets value of the input elements
- `.text` gets/sets the innerText of elements

Comment: I don't get it, what do you mean remove dateSelected? That's where I set the value

Comment: It says "Remove dateSelected if you're not wanting to set a value.". You may keep it, read later on for explanation. I think I made it pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

If the [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val) method is called without arguments, then the function returns current value of an `<input>` (or `<select>`, or `<textarea>`) element. If the method is used to set the value , then the the set of matched element will be returned.

So, you should use

```
console.log(dateCat.val());
```

or

```
var dateCat = $(".time_value").val(dateSelected).val();
console.log(dateCat);
```

to display a new value.

Answer (score 0):

If you give an element with the class 'usp-input-category' then you will get the value.

```js
$("#sandbox-container span").on("click", function(e) {
      $("#sandbox-container span").removeClass("selected_year");
      $(this).attr("class", "selected_year");
      var dateSelected = $(".selected_year").text();
      var dateCat = $(".usp-input-category").val(dateSelected);
      console.log(dateSelected);
      console.log(dateCat.val());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sandbox-container">
      <span class="selected_year">2014</span>
      <span>2018</span>
    </div>
    <input class="usp-input-category"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value of an element using jQuery [`.val(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2). This does not return the value you have set. You may check the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2).

You may retrieve  the value using `$(".usp-input-category").val();`.

The logic does not make much sense here. But as you are insistent on following this logic, you may do like:

```
var dateSelected = $(".selected_year").text();
$(".usp-input-category").val(dateSelected);
var dateCat = $(".usp-input-category").val();
```

This should give you the correct answer you expect.

For explanations regarding the `r.fn.init [prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]` output you were getting, you can refer [this SO question and answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34495444/5982321)